Tensor product of two modules that are projective over different rings
This is in regards to the proof of Weibels Corollary 9.1.5:
Suppose $A$ is a projective module over a comm. ring $k$. I have already proven, that this implies $A^{\otimes n}$ is also $k$-projective. The next step is, that this implies $A^e \otimes A^{\otimes n}$ is $A^e$-projective. ($A^e = A \otimes A^{op}$, and $\otimes = \otimes_k$ everywhere). Obviously $A^e$ is $A^e$-projective.
Edit: Forgot to define $A^{op}$: Suppose $A$ also has an algebra structure. $A^{op}$ is the same as $A$ as an module, but with $a \cdot_{op} b = b \cdot a$.
I'm currently stuck on this point, how can I show this?

Sorry, what is $A^{op}$?

@PCeltide added an edit, sorry

could you try some form of adjunction? $Hom_R(R\otimes_k M, N) = Hom_k(M, Hom_R(R,N))=Hom_k(M,N)$, and then being projective means homs out of the module is right exact.

Yeah, I don't see why that wouldn't work, thanks!
